# How to recognize paused queue/broker on messageProducer.send(message)

Tags: java, payara, openmq

I am trying to add the option to stop production and consumption of messages for a specific  queue/destination.

The way I found is to call the `imqcmd` and pause/resume the physical destination. Doing so, the message is not ending up in the paused queue which is great but unfortunately the program is not informed about that.

Instead it just "stops" on the send operation. It does not print anything stepping with the debugger doesnt acomplish anything. The debugger only says

```
Waiting until last debugger command completes
```

When I resume the queue again during this state it immediately jumps to the next breakpoint.

As an alternative I tried pausing the broker which also results in the message not being sent and at least I get the following warning

```
[__ejb-thread-pool9] WARN  com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.AckQueue:338 - [W2003]: Broker not responding [MAP_MESSAGE(3)] for 7560 seconds. Still trying...,
```

Is there a way to get an exception when `messageProducer.send(message)` is executed for a paused queue or a paused broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thank you very much for improving the structure of my question. May I ask why you removed the jms tag?

Comment: I removed the `jms` tag because your question is specifically about OpenMQ's non-spec behavior (i.e. pausing a queue).